# Can you wrap a javascript app in a java container?

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, web-applications

I have a professor that insists we code our app in Java. No one in my group really knows Java. He said we are free to include JavaScript and HTML and CSS.

We want to know how we can essentially make an HTML, JavaScript, CSS app and just wrap it/ embedded it in a Java app. I'm not sure where to start.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can build Java web application with frontend using HTML, JavaScript and all that stuff and Java on server side.
Check these links:
http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-with-static-content-css-and-javascript-js and 
https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-springboot-angularjs-bootstrap-springdata-j

Comment: One of the Faces libraries might also work, like Prime, Rich or ICE Faces - haven't messed with SpringBoot so not sure which might get the OP up and running quicker